# Approver cannot see email to approve

Tags: marketing-cloud, approval-process

I have sent my email off to my approver but when he opens it up, the panel displays  "Error not found".

I have tried sending it again and this issue still persists.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with the Ampscript in the email that was breaking this. Once this was fixed, the problem went away